# Why is my code terminating immediately?

Tags: java, while-loop, fibonacci

I'm trying to print out all the positive numbers of the Fibonacci sequence that are lower than four million.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n1 = 1;
    int n2 = 2;
    int n3 = 0;

    while (n3 <= 4000000) {
        n3 = n1 + n2;
        if (n3 % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(n3);
        }
        n1+=1;
        n2+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing that modulo check?  That would only ever print out even numbers in the sequence.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors on running the code? Also, this is not the algorithm to use to print out the fibonacci sequence... *n1* and *n2* are not supposed to be incremented

Comment: That's not the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are not calculating Fibonacci numbers. However even if you did, this should execute so fast, you won't see it calculating the result.

You need all the even Fibonacci values. Every third Fibonacci is even so you don't need to check each one.  You can do

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = a + b;
long sum = 0;
while (c < 4_000_000) {
   sum += c;
   a = b + c;
   b = a + c;
   c = a + b; // skip forward to the next even fibonacci
}
```

Note: this drop a `%` which is expensive and has 1/3rd of the loops.

Answer (score 6):

Your logic is incorrect.

If you were to step through this code in a debugger you would see that `n3` is ***never*** even (what you are testing for in `n3 % 2 == 0`), so the `if` condition is never true.

It does not take long for a modern processor to count to 4 million (a few dozen milliseconds at most) so it appears the program terminates immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not terminate immediately, it just doesn't print anything. `n1` starts out as 1 and `n2` as 2, giving a sum of 3, which is odd - and thus not printed. Each iteration of the loop increments both numbers, giving another odd result, and again, printing nothing.

Fibonacci numbers, however, have nothing to do with even numbers - they are just the sum of the two previous numbers in the series:

```
while (n3 <= 4000000) {
    n3 = n1 + n2;
    System.out.println(n3);
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you are not establishing `n1` and `n2` correctly at the end of the loop.  Don't just add `1` to each of `n1` and `n2`.  Because you're doing just incrementing each of `n1` and `n2`, one of them is odd and one of them is even at all times.  This makes `n3` odd, so it's never printed.  Instead, set `n1` to `n2`, then `n2` to `n3`.

Second, all numbers of the Fibonacci sequence are positive, so there is no reason to place a condition on the print.  That condition would print only the even ones, anyway.  Remove the `if`, leaving the print.

Answer (score 0):

**Why is my code terminating immediately?**(Not going for the logic)

Because your code is not printing anything as the condition `if (n3 % 2 == 0)` is always false ( `n3` is always odd ),***remove the the if condition and it will not terminate immediately*** because printing takes some time.